# Using cURL, explode and foreach to check for 403 response code

Tags: php, curl, foreach

Okay so I'm making a script to check if given website(s) return a 403 or not. I joined some bits and pieces to get this working and it does work if I just check a single website at a time but it doesn't not work with multiple websites.

```
$url = $_POST['site'];

$many_urls = explode(",", $url);

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 403 (forbidden). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

foreach ($many_urls as $urls)
{
    if($httpCode == 403) {
        echo "<h2>$url is <font color='red'>Forbidden.</font><h2>";
    } else echo "<h2>$url <font color='green'>Works.</font><h2>";
}

curl_close($handle);
```

So if I type in for example: **google.com,youtube.com,forbiddenwebsite.com**

It should return:

google.com **Works** youtube.com **Works** forbiddenwebsite.com is **Forbidden** (on different lines ofcourse)

I'm pretty sure there's a problem with **foreach** part.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're going to be checking each url independently when in list form, you'll need to have that curl in the loop. otherwise you're checking the headers for "google.com,youtube.com,forbiddenwebsite.com", which isn't a valid address. try this:

```
/* exploding the url list will give an array with 1 item in the case of only 1 url */
$urls = explode(',', $_POST['site']);

/* wrap the whole thing in the loop, check each url individually */
foreach($urls as $url){

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    /* Check for 403 (forbidden). */
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($httpCode == 403) {
        echo "<h2>$url is <font color='red'>Forbidden.</font><h2>";
    } else echo "<h2>$url <font color='green'>Works.</font><h2>";


    curl_close($handle);
}
```

You'll probably want to add some sort of check for the case of an empty string passed in the post vars too.

Comment: Wow this worked! Thanks a lot. Now is there a way to make this thing even better or faster?

Comment: If all you're looking for is the response code from the headers, you might check out the [`get_headers` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)